# json_encode() in PHP returns Chinese characters in escaped Unicode

Tags: php, json

I’ve got a simple PHP one-dimension array.

When I do a var dump (`echo var_dump($a)`), I get this as the output:

```
array(3) { [0]=>  string(3) "尽" [1]=>  string(21) "exhausted||to exhaust" [2]=>  string(4) "jin3" }
```

However, when I json_encode it (`echo json_encode($a)`) I get this:

```
["\u5c3d","exhausted||to exhaust","jin3"]
```

The hex value that it’s returning is the correct one, but I can’t figure out how to **stop** it from giving me the hex.  I just want it to display the character.

If I `echo mb_internal_encoding()` it returns UTF-8, which is what I’ve set it to. I’ve been very careful in all my string manipulation to use the mb_ functions so none of the data gets messed up.

I know that I could write a modified json_encode function which would take care of the problem.  But I want to know what’s going on here.

Comment: The JSON it is generating is equivalent to the JSON with the character written explicitly. Now, writing the character explicitly would be easier to read, and take less bytes, but the two JSON strings are nonetheless equivalent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Json_encode Charset problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035462/json-encode-charset-problem)

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is older but thought I'd lend my working–in–China `to_json` and `to_utf8` functions — which includes some nice formatting (JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) when in development vs minified production. (Adapt to your own env/system)

### Simple

```
// Produces JSON with Chinese Characters fully un-encoded.
// NOT RFC4627 compliant
json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

### to_json()

```
function to_json($data, $pretty=null, $inculde_security=false, $try_to_recover=true) {
  // @Note: json_encode() *REQUIRES* data to be in valid UTF8 format BEFORE
  //                    trying to json_encode   and since we are working with Chinese
  //                    characters, we need to make sure that we explicitly allow:
  //                    JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES
  //                    *Unless a mode is explicitly passed into the function
    $json_encoded = '{}';
    if ($pretty === null && is_env_prod()) { // @NOTE: Substitute with your own Production env check
        $json_encoded = json_encode( $data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES );
    } else if ($pretty === null && is_env_dev()){ // @NOTE: Substitute with your own Development env check
        $json_encoded = json_encode( $data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES );
    } else {
        // PRODUCTION
        $json_encoded = json_encode( $data, $pretty );
    }



    // (1) Do not return an error if the inital data was empty
    // (2) Return an error if json_encode() failed
    if (json_last_error() > 0) {
        if (!!$data || !empty($data)) {
            if (!$json_encoded == false || empty($json_encoded) || $json_encoded == '{}') {
                $json_encoded = json_encode([
                    'status' => false,
                    'error' => [
                        'json_last_error' => json_last_error(),
                        'json_last_error_msg' => json_last_error_msg()
                    ]
                ]);
            } else if (!!$try_to_recover) {
                // there was data in $data so lets try to forensically recover a little? by removing $k => $v pairs that fail to be JSON encoded
                foreach (((array) $data) as $k => $v) {
                    if (!json_encode([$k => $v])) {
                        if (is_array($data)) {
                            unset($data[$k]);
                        } else if (is_object($data)) {
                            unset($data->{$k});
                        }
                    }
                }

                // if the data still is not empty, and there is a status set in the data
                //      then set it to false and add a error message/data
                //      ONLY for Array & Objects
                if (!empty($json_encoded) && count($json_encoded) < 1) {
                    if (!json_encode($data)) {
                        if (is_array($json_encoded)) {
                            $json_encoded['status'] = false;
                            $json_encoded['message'] = "json_encoding_error";
                            $json_encoded['error'] = [
                                'json_last_error' => json_last_error(),
                                'json_last_error_msg' => json_last_error_msg()
                            ];
                        } else if (is_object($json_encoded)) {
                            $json_encoded->status = false;
                            $json_encoded->message = "json_encoding_error";
                            $json_encoded->error = [
                                'json_last_error' => json_last_error(),
                                'json_last_error_msg' => json_last_error_msg()
                            ];
                        }
                    } else {
                      // We have removed the offending data
                      return to_json($data, $pretty, $include_security, $try_to_recover);
                    }
                }

                // we've cleaned out any data that was causing the problem, and included
                //      false to indicate this is a one-time recursion recovery.
                return $this->to_json($pretty, $include_security, false);
            }
        } else { } // don't do anything as the value is already false
    }

  return ( ($inculde_security) ? ")]}',\n" : '' ) . $json_encoded;
}
```

---

Another funciton that might be usful is my recursive `to_utf8()` functionality:

### to_utf8()

```
// @NOTE: Common Chinese GBK encoding: to_utf8($data, 'GB2312')
function to_utf8($in, $source_encoding='HTML-ENTITIES') {
  if (is_string($in)) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(
      $in,
      $source_encoding,
      'UTF-8'
    );
  } else if (is_array($in) || is_object($in)) {

    array_walk_recursive($in, function(&$item, &$key) {
      $key = to_utf8($key);

      if (is_object($item) || is_array($item)) {
        $item = to_utf8($item);
      } else {
        if (!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'UTF-8', true)){
          $item = utf8_encode($item);
        }
      }
    });

    $ret_object = is_object($in);
    return ($ret_object) ? (object) $in : (array) $in;
  }

  return $in;
}
```

---

### Validate RFC4627 (valid JSON)

```
$pcre_regex = '
  /
  (?(DEFINE)
     (?<number>   -? (?= [1-9]|0(?!\d) ) \d+ (\.\d+)? ([eE] [+-]? \d+)? )
     (?<boolean>   true | false | null )
     (?<string>    " ([^"\\\\]* | \\\\ ["\\\\bfnrt\/] | \\\\ u [0-9a-f]{4} )* " )
     (?<array>     \[  (?:  (?&json)  (?: , (?&json)  )*  )?  \s* \] )
     (?<pair>      \s* (?&string) \s* : (?&json)  )
     (?<object>    \{  (?:  (?&pair)  (?: , (?&pair)  )*  )?  \s* \} )
     (?<json>   \s* (?: (?&number) | (?&boolean) | (?&string) | (?&array) | (?&object) ) \s* )
  )
  \A (?&json) \Z
  /six
';

$matches = false;
preg_match($pcre_regex, trim($body), $matches);

var_dump('RFC4627 Verification (Regex) ', [
  'has_passed' => (count($matches) == 1) ? 'YES' : 'NO',
  'matches'    => $matches
]);
```

### is_json()

```
// One Liner
is_string($json_string) && !preg_match('/[^,:{}\\[\\]0-9.\\-+Eaeflnr-u \\n\\r\\t]/', preg_replace('/"(\\.|[^"\\\\])*"/', '', $json_string));

// Alt Function — more consistant
function is_json($json_string) {
  if (!is_string($json_string) || is_numeric($json_string)) {
      return false;
  }

  $val = @json_decode($json_string);

  return ($val != null) && (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE);

  // Inconsistant results, reverted to json_decode() + JSON_ERROR_NONE check
  // return is_string($json_string) && !preg_match('/[^,:{}\\[\\]0-9.\\-+Eaeflnr-u \\n\\r\\t]/', preg_replace('/"(\\.|[^"\\\\])*"/', '', $json_string));
}
```

### is_utf8()

```
function is_utf8($str) {
  if (is_array($str)) {
    foreach ($str as $k=>$v) {
      if (is_string($v) && !is_utf8($v)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  return (is_string($str) && preg_match('//u', $str));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour of `json_encode()` is perfectly correct, but unnecessary. In PHP 5.4, it can be disabled with the [JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) flag.

Comment: had the exact same problem, but with Greek characters, and this solved it!

Comment: Just curious, @Dio. What actual *problem* was this causing?

Comment: the resulting page would render garbage characters iirc

Comment: This is the correct answer to me. Please get ticked as the solution! Thank you!

Comment: @QinWang. That's up to the asker, and he was last seen in 2010.

Answer (score 2):

try this you are posting data in json and want to submit chines or Japaneses or Koran or any other language characters

```
 json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've did the same investigation on `json_encode()`. My conclusion is that **you cannot alter the behavior**, yet it doesn't cause any problem so I will just leave with that.

If you really don't like it, do `preg_replace_callback()` on `json_encode()` output and convert the code point hex back into UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql to create the array you can use:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

This will create a result in utf8.

I have not tried but you may wish to look at [utf8_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) and [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) functions in php.

Comment: It has the data in UTF-8 (if it didn't, `json_encode()` would return `null`). The Unicode-escaping is just the way `json_encode()` works, but it can be turned off. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> json_encode()

has some options
use this way

> ```
> json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
> ```