# Json_encode Charset problem

Tags: php, json, localization, character-encoding

When I use json_encode to encode my multi lingual strings , It also changes special characters.What should I do to keep them same .

For example

```
<?
echo json_encode(array('şüğçö'));
```

It returns something like ["\u015f\u00fc\u011f\u00e7\u00f6"]

But I want ["şüğçö"]

Comment: This is the solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why are my "special" Unicode characters encoded weird using json\_encode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745662/reference-why-are-my-special-unicode-characters-encoded-weird-using-json-enco)

Answer (score 8):

try it:

```
<?
echo json_encode(array('şüğçö'), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Answer (score 2):

In JSON any character in strings may be represented by a Unicode escape sequence. Thus `"\u015f\u00fc\u011f\u00e7\u00f6"` is semantically equal to `"şüğçö"`.

Although those character can also be used plain, `json_encode` probably prefers the Unicode escape sequences to avoid character encoding issues.

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.4 adds the option `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`, which does what you want. Note that `json_encode` always outputs UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

- **You shouldn't want this**
- It's definitely possible, even without PHP 5.4.

First, use `json_encode()` to encode the string and save it in a variable.

Then simply use `preg_replace()` to replace all \uxxxx with unicode again.

Comment: Wait, did I just reply to a question that's more than a year old? :-/

Answer (score 1):

[`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) does not provide any options for choosing the charset the encoding is in in versions prior to 5.4.

Comment: @Tom: Is that why you downvoted an answer that was accurate when it was written?

Comment: Haha, I just realized I did that. I'm sorry - vote removed. I have no idea why I even viewed this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

print_r(json_decode(json_encode(array('şüğçö'))));

/*
Array
(   
    [0] => şüğçö
)
*/
```

So do you really need to keep these characters unescaped in the JSON?

Comment: yes because I pass it to HTML via ajax request , and I can not see special characters

Comment: @Oguz: Ajax (e.g. asynchronous requests via JavaScript) do not depend on JSON.

Comment: Then you're doing something else wrong - Ajax will definitely interpret the `\u00e7` characters just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Json_encode charset solution for **PHP 5.3.3**

As `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` is not working in PHP 5.3.3 so we have used this method and it is working.

```
$data = array(
        'text' => 'Päiväkampanjat'
);
$json_encode = json_encode($data);
var_dump($json_encode); // text: "P\u00e4iv\u00e4kampanjat"

$unescaped_data = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u(\w{4})/', function ($matches) {
    return html_entity_decode('&#x' . $matches[1] . ';', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
}, $json_encode);

var_dump($unescaped); // text is unescaped -> Päiväkampanjat
```