# How to produce JSON - un-escaped unicodes in php 5.3.x

Tags: php, json, serialization, unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Json_encode Charset problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035462/json-encode-charset-problem)

How can I produce JSON unescaped unicodes in php 5.3.x ?

**example:**

`array("name"=>"some unicode chars");`

will be JSONed like this :

`{"name":"\Uxxx\Uyyy\Uzzz\Usss \U123......."}`

where `xxx` and `yyy` are the equivalent unicode values of the characters in the original array.

Now I need the JSON to output like this:

`{"name":"some unicode chars"}`

Comment: Why? The JSON parser on the other end will handle the escapes perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes I think it's doing it the proper way already.

Comment: And eschwing them might even make it non-compliant, so that some JSON parsers do not decode it afterwards.

Comment: Well when you have 10 paragraphs in a page all in unicode characters ( size would increas 4-5 times each character is changed to 5 characters

Comment: I have checked the source of the page in Google+ and Facebook+ and all the Ajax requests. . then don't encode unicode characters in JSONs